# Return Only Last Row LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT DISTINCT msg.userid, msg.messages, user.fullname, prof.path
FROM messages AS msg
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON msg.userid = md5( user.userid )
LEFT JOIN profile AS prof ON msg.userid = prof.userid
ORDER BY msg.date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The above code is working but the problem is that the result has duplicate values:

```
userid | messages | fullname | path
985434 | hello... | Foo Bar  | /path/to/hello.jpg
985434 | hello... | Foo Bar  | /path/to/new.jpg
```

The problem is the `PATH`. **How to limit the result of `path` into the most recent? or only one per fullname?...It's killing me** Thank you for understanding.

Comment: use group by msg.userid

Comment: yes..is there a way to limit the left join into 1...i tried subqueries and put LIMIT 0,1 ..the problem is all other path except the first became ```null```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is select users messages. You also want to select one path per message. Here is an example on how to do this:

```
SELECT msg.userid, msg.messages, users.fullname, 
  (select max(path) from profile where profile.userid = msg.userid) as maxpath
FROM messages AS msg
LEFT JOIN users ON msg.userid = md5( users.userid )
ORDER BY msg.date ASC;
```

You can also use group_concat instead of max, to get a list of all paths. Also the sub select can be more complex, with looking for the last date for instance (provided there is a date information in that table).

Why do you left outer join users to messages by the way? Are there messages without associated users?

Comment: Thank you so much! can you recommend any e-books or tutorials on how to improve my sql skill?

Comment: @user3204806 - Be wary here, this picks the `MAX(path)` by sorting all the paths alphanumerically.  It does *NOT* pick the *most recent* path.

Comment: @MatBailie. That is true. To get the most recent path there had to be a date information in profiles and the sub select statement would get more complex as I said above.

Comment: @user3204806: No, sorry. I've been using SQL for many, many years now, so there was no need for e-books or online tutorials for me recently.

Comment: @MatBailie thanks...I modify the query and its working fine now. Thanks people for help

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` all the paths and using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` on the group to pick first path you can also use order by in `GROUP_CONCAT( prof.path order by some_col DESC )` like

```
SELECT 
 msg.userid,
 msg.messages, 
 user.fullname, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT( prof.path ),',',1) AS path
FROM messages AS msg
LEFT JOIN users AS USER ON msg.userid = MD5( user.userid )
LEFT JOIN profile AS prof ON msg.userid = prof.userid
GROUP BY msg.userid
ORDER BY msg.date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```